# Fractional Sobolev norm of the modulus of a function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $H^s(\mathbf{R}^d)$ be the Sobolev space with $s \in (0,1]$. It is known that if $u \in H^1(\mathbf{R}^d)$ then also $|u| \in H^1(\mathbf{R}^d)$ with equality of the norms $\| u \|_{H^1} = \| |u| \|_{H^1}$. I would like to see if something similar holds in the fractional case $s \in (0,1)$. Using the Gagliardo seminorm
$$
[u]_{H^s}^2 = \int_{\mathbf{R}^d} \int_{\mathbf{R}^d} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} \; dxdy
$$
it is easy to show that if $u \in H^s$ then $|u| \in H^s$ with $\| |u| \|_{H^s} \leq \| u \|_{H^s}$, because $ ||u(x)| - |u(y)|| \leq |u(x) - u(y)|$. Is the converse inequality true, maybe up to a constant which does not depend on $u$? I was trying to show this using the characterization
$$
\| u \|_{H^s} = \sup_{\| v \|_{H^{-s}} \leq 1} \int_{\mathbf{R}^d} uv \; dx
$$
with an appropriate choice of $v$, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse inequality
$$
\| u \|_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\lesssim
\| ~ |u| ~ \|_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)}
$$
is true for $s \in (1/2,1)$, but not below $1/2$.

This is proved in the paper [Remark on the absolute value in Sobolev spaces](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1016/j.crma.2011.05.003.pdf) by Pierre Gilles Lemarié-Rieusset.